# Sent to wrong address!

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind

:( Hi I need some help, I ordered some bit coin from bitcoin.co.uk and sent them what I thought was my wallet address on mycelium, but what I sent them was a qr code address when u click on recive! Will it be sent to that at code or will it just be lost? And if it’s not do I just need to scan that qr code with a different wallet qr scanner?? :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes the address in QR code is your address. so no worries your bitcoins has to go to your wallet.